HTTP ERROR 412 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 412 () ( using xampp-apache )
My idea is to use Google Sign-In (GSI) to authenticate with a Google account using just html and js. Im using this index.html to do it:
As you see, data login uri is ".....home.html" 
All's right, but when I get home.html and press F5, that error appears.
The strangest thing is that when I press F5 again, the error dissappears and so on.
Anyway, I would like to see any full example if possible to do it...The main idea is to stay there in same page even if you reload the page to use Google Drive files.
Thanks!
